# optimistic-serialization in weblogic.xml file - ClassCastException

Tags: java, xml, weblogic

The `weblogic.xml` file has a tag for ["optimistic-serialization"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/webapp/weblogic_xml.html) and the document says that:

> When optimistic-serialization is turned off (default value), WebLogic
>   Server serialize-deserializes context and request attributes upon
>   getAttribute(name) to avoid the possibility of ClassCastExceptions.

Please help me in understanding this, why we will get ClassCastExceptions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer lies in the fact that the application classes are loaded in different/separate classloaders. That means each classloader can have its own version of the classes. If Weblogic didn't perform the serialization as described above in your question, the wrong class may be used during a cast causing `ClassCastException`.

The overhead of that serialization is small if you're making a remote call but can be wasteful/slow/costly if it's local communication.

Comment: To my understanding if I have a web application then the application class loader will load all my classes, so I have only 1 class loader and this maintains a single version for the classes of my application. Why weblogic tries to cast to a wrong object and result in ClassCastException? Can you please give some examples so it helps me to understand better.

Comment: If you only have one application and/or no remote calls from your application, you won't need to worry about this problem.